# Select fields clear values but ignore the first option

Tags: jquery

I am using the `^` on a selector to find all options with that id starting with form1_product to hide all the values and clear them. then switch to display the correct select option.

This is all working but the question I have is

**How do I ignore the first option in the options list because currently it strips all values out.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  toggleFields();

  $("#form1_segment").change(function() {
    toggleFields();
  });

  function toggleFields() {

    $("[id^=form1_product]").hide().val(null);

    switch ($("#form1_segment").val()) {
      case "Food Service":
        $("#form1_product").show();
        break;
      case "Building Care":
        $("#form1_product_bc").show();
        break;
      case "Industry":
        $("#form1_product_in").show();
        break;
      case "Health Care":
        $("#form1_product_hc").show();
        break;
      case "Automotive":
        $("#form1_product_auto").show();
        break;
      case "Aerospace":
        $("#form1_product_aero").show();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1_contact" class="contact-form" action="/en-us/contact" method="post">
  <div>
    <input id="form1_name" name="name" class="contact-form__input" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" required="required" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="form1_email" name="email" class="contact-form__input" placeholder="Email address" type="email" required="required" />
  </div>
  <div class="split-form">
    <label for="form1_segment">Segment</label>
    <select id="form1_segment" name="segment" class="test">
      <option value="Select a Segment">Select a Segment</option>
      <option value="Food Service">Food Service</option>
      <option value="Building Care">Building Care</option>
      <option value="Industry">Industry</option>
      <option value="Health Care">Health Care</option>
      <option value="Automotive">Automotive</option>
      <option value="Aerospace">Aerospace</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="split-form last">
    <label for="form1_product">Product</label>
    <select id="form1_product" name="product" class="test">
      <option value="Select a product">Select a product</option>
      <option value="S.U.D.S.® Single Use Dispensing System">S.U.D.S.® Single Use Dispensing System</option>
      <option value="Chix® SC Foodservice Towels">Chix® SC Foodservice Towels</option>
      <option value="Chix® SC Foodservice Towels">Chix® SC Foodservice Towels</option>
      <option value="Chix® Pro-Quat®">Chix® Pro-Quat®</option>
      <option value="Chix® Pro-Quat®">Chix® Pro-Quat®</option>
      <option value="Chix® Pro-Quat®">Chix® Pro-Quat®</option>
      <option value="Chix® Pro-Chlor®">Chix® Pro-Chlor®</option>
      <option value="Chix® Microfiber Light Cloths">Chix® Microfiber Light Cloths</option>
      <option value="Chix® Plus with Microban">Chix® Plus with Microban</option>
      <option value="Chix® Towels with Microban">Chix® Towels with Microban</option>
      <option value="Chix® Towels">Chix® Towels</option>
      <option value="Chix® Plus Sanitizing">Chix® Plus Sanitizing</option>
      <option value="Chix® Soft Cloth">Chix® Soft Cloth</option>
      <option value="Chix® Tough">Chix® Tough</option>
      <option value="Chix® All Day™">Chix® All Day™</option>
      <option value="Chix® Wet Wipes">Chix® Wet Wipes</option>
      <option value="Chix® Competitive Wet Wipes">Chix® Competitive Wet Wipes</option>
      <option value="Chix® Economy Towels">Chix® Economy Towels</option>
      <option value="Chix® 3000">Chix® 3000</option>
      <option value="Quix® Pretreated Towels">Quix® Pretreated Towels</option>
      <option value="Chix® Apron">Chix® Apron</option>
      <option value="Worxwell®">Worxwell®</option>
    </select>
    <select id="form1_product_bc" name="product_bc" class="test">
      <option value="Select a product">Select a product</option>
      <option value="Dusty™ High Performance Dust Cloth">Dusty™ High Performance Dust Cloth</option>
      <option value="Masslinn® Heavy Duty Dust Cloth">Masslinn® Heavy Duty Dust Cloth</option>
      <option value="S.U.D.S.® Single Use Dispensing System">S.U.D.S.® Single Use Dispensing System</option>
      <option value="Masslinn® Medium Duty Dust Cloth">Masslinn® Medium Duty Dust Cloth</option>
      <option value="Masslinn® Light Duty Dust Cloth">Masslinn® Light Duty Dust Cloth</option>
      <option value="Economy Duster">Economy Duster</option>
      <option value="Masslinn Dusting Tools">Masslinn Dusting Tools</option>
    </select>
    <select id="form1_product_in" name="product_in" class="test">
      <option value="Select a product">Select a product</option>
      <option value="Durawipe® Heavy Duty Shop Towel">Durawipe® Heavy Duty Shop Towel</option>
    </select>
    <select id="form1_product_hc" name="product_hc" class="test">
      <option value="Select a product">Select a product</option>
      <option value="Worxwell® Towels">Worxwell® Towels</option>
      <option value="Soft Cloth Patient Wipes">Soft Cloth Patient Wipes</option>
      <option value="Professional Series">Professional Series</option>
      <option value="Dwell™ Disinfectant Compatible Healthcare Towels">Dwell™ Disinfectant Compatible Healthcare Towels</option>
      <option value="Dusty™ High Performance Dust Cloths">Dusty™ High Performance Dust Cloths</option>
    </select>
    <select id="form1_product_auto" name="product_auto" class="test">
      <option value="No products available">No products available</option>
    </select>
    <select id="form1_product_aero" name="product_aero" class="test">
      <option value="No products available">No products available</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <textarea id="form1_message" name="message" class="contact-form__input  contact-form__textarea" cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="form1_submit" name="submit" class="btn  btn__round  subform__button" value="Send Message" type="submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Use `:not()` with `:first-child` to exclude the first option in each select: `$("[id^=form1_product]:not(:first-child)").hide().val(null);` Also, setting the value of `option` elements on the fly sounds like a bad idea. I'm pretty sure there's a much easier and DRY-er way of doing what you need. We'd need to see your HTML to be sure though

Comment: `$("[id^=form1_product]:not(:first-child)").hide().val(null);` I tried this, but it broke the switch case and displayed all the fields

Comment: We really need to see the HTML to help you then.

Comment: I updated my question to run the snippet of code if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `value` to `null` makes it so that no option is selected, not the first one (which has a value of "Select a product" or "No products available"). I think you actually want to select the first option on each `select`.

The following code hides the `select`s as previously, deselects all of the options, then selects the first one. There are other ways of doing that, this is just what happened to pop in my head.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  toggleFields();

  $("#form1_segment").change(function() {
    toggleFields();
  });

  function toggleFields() {

    $("[id^=form1_product]").hide().find('option').prop('selected', false).first().prop('selected', true);

    switch ($("#form1_segment").val()) {
      case "Food Service":
        $("#form1_product").show();
        break;
      case "Building Care":
        $("#form1_product_bc").show();
        break;
      case "Industry":
        $("#form1_product_in").show();
        break;
      case "Health Care":
        $("#form1_product_hc").show();
        break;
      case "Automotive":
        $("#form1_product_auto").show();
        break;
      case "Aerospace":
        $("#form1_product_aero").show();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1_contact" class="contact-form" action="/en-us/contact" method="post">
  <div>
    <input id="form1_name" name="name" class="contact-form__input" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" required="required" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="form1_email" name="email" class="contact-form__input" placeholder="Email address" type="email" required="required" />
  </div>
  <div class="split-form">
    <label for="form1_segment">Segment</label>
    <select id="form1_segment" name="segment" class="test">
      <option value="Select a Segment">Select a Segment</option>
      <option value="Food Service">Food Service</option>
      <option value="Building Care">Building Care</option>
      <option value="Industry">Industry</option>
      <option value="Health Care">Health Care</option>
      <option value="Automotive">Automotive</option>
      <option value="Aerospace">Aerospace</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="split-form last">
    <label for="form1_product">Product</label>
    <select id="form1_product" name="product" class="test">
      <option value="Select a product">Select a product</option>
      <option value="S.U.D.S.® Single Use Dispensing System">S.U.D.S.® Single Use Dispensing System</option>
      <option value="Chix® SC Foodservice Towels">Chix® SC Foodservice Towels</option>
      <option value="Chix® SC Foodservice Towels">Chix® SC Foodservice Towels</option>
      <option value="Chix® Pro-Quat®">Chix® Pro-Quat®</option>
      <option value="Chix® Pro-Quat®">Chix® Pro-Quat®</option>
      <option value="Chix® Pro-Quat®">Chix® Pro-Quat®</option>
      <option value="Chix® Pro-Chlor®">Chix® Pro-Chlor®</option>
      <option value="Chix® Microfiber Light Cloths">Chix® Microfiber Light Cloths</option>
      <option value="Chix® Plus with Microban">Chix® Plus with Microban</option>
      <option value="Chix® Towels with Microban">Chix® Towels with Microban</option>
      <option value="Chix® Towels">Chix® Towels</option>
      <option value="Chix® Plus Sanitizing">Chix® Plus Sanitizing</option>
      <option value="Chix® Soft Cloth">Chix® Soft Cloth</option>
      <option value="Chix® Tough">Chix® Tough</option>
      <option value="Chix® All Day™">Chix® All Day™</option>
      <option value="Chix® Wet Wipes">Chix® Wet Wipes</option>
      <option value="Chix® Competitive Wet Wipes">Chix® Competitive Wet Wipes</option>
      <option value="Chix® Economy Towels">Chix® Economy Towels</option>
      <option value="Chix® 3000">Chix® 3000</option>
      <option value="Quix® Pretreated Towels">Quix® Pretreated Towels</option>
      <option value="Chix® Apron">Chix® Apron</option>
      <option value="Worxwell®">Worxwell®</option>
    </select>
    <select id="form1_product_bc" name="product_bc" class="test">
      <option value="Select a product">Select a product</option>
      <option value="Dusty™ High Performance Dust Cloth">Dusty™ High Performance Dust Cloth</option>
      <option value="Masslinn® Heavy Duty Dust Cloth">Masslinn® Heavy Duty Dust Cloth</option>
      <option value="S.U.D.S.® Single Use Dispensing System">S.U.D.S.® Single Use Dispensing System</option>
      <option value="Masslinn® Medium Duty Dust Cloth">Masslinn® Medium Duty Dust Cloth</option>
      <option value="Masslinn® Light Duty Dust Cloth">Masslinn® Light Duty Dust Cloth</option>
      <option value="Economy Duster">Economy Duster</option>
      <option value="Masslinn Dusting Tools">Masslinn Dusting Tools</option>
    </select>
    <select id="form1_product_in" name="product_in" class="test">
      <option value="Select a product">Select a product</option>
      <option value="Durawipe® Heavy Duty Shop Towel">Durawipe® Heavy Duty Shop Towel</option>
    </select>
    <select id="form1_product_hc" name="product_hc" class="test">
      <option value="Select a product">Select a product</option>
      <option value="Worxwell® Towels">Worxwell® Towels</option>
      <option value="Soft Cloth Patient Wipes">Soft Cloth Patient Wipes</option>
      <option value="Professional Series">Professional Series</option>
      <option value="Dwell™ Disinfectant Compatible Healthcare Towels">Dwell™ Disinfectant Compatible Healthcare Towels</option>
      <option value="Dusty™ High Performance Dust Cloths">Dusty™ High Performance Dust Cloths</option>
    </select>
    <select id="form1_product_auto" name="product_auto" class="test">
      <option value="No products available">No products available</option>
    </select>
    <select id="form1_product_aero" name="product_aero" class="test">
      <option value="No products available">No products available</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <textarea id="form1_message" name="message" class="contact-form__input  contact-form__textarea" cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="form1_submit" name="submit" class="btn  btn__round  subform__button" value="Send Message" type="submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```